# Maven cargo and buildnumber plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-cargo, build-numbers

Is there anybody out there who has combine the both maven plugins Cargo and Buildnumber work together ? I can create a property 'buildNumber' from the BuildNumber plugin well, but this property isn't propagated into the Cargo plugin. As mentions [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MBUILDNUM-26) this issue was adressing back in 2008/2009 but still not really fixed.

my pom.xml

```
<version>0.1</version>
...
<finalName>webapp-${project.version}.${buildNumber}</finalName>
```

The buildNumber was properly extract from the SCM.
The war file packaged by the maven-war plugin has the correct filename (e.g. webapp-0.1.460.war)
But the Cargo plugin doesn't know anything about ${buildNumber}

```
FileNotFoundException: target/webapp-0.1.${buildNumber}.war (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: faced the same problem.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?